# Hosting a rails app inside another website's directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a php site on my server, suppose it is `example.com`.
And I want to run an rails app inside the domain like `example.com/rails`.
I am using nginx and tried to edit the example.com's host config and proxied the `/rails` location to unicorn upstream. But that did not work.

Is it possible to do like `example.com/rails` ?

Comment: Your approach is correct, please post your configuration, and be more specific about "But that did not work."

Comment: it is throwing error 404.

Comment: Note the 'please post your configuration' part.